# Firefox cannot access a frequently visited website anymore

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I have tried unsuccessfully all the troubleshooting available from Firefox but I keep getting the same error:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://vodlocker.com/wv420ypnzarv
    Connection to host failed.
The system returned: (110) Connection timed out
The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.
```

I can access the website with my other computer, and I used to do it with this computer too.

Is there a way to block access to an URL in Ubuntu?

Where should that code be stored?

Comment: Can you access the website with another browser? For example midori to install midori: sudo apt-get install midori After that, launch Midori from the Dash and try out the website. If that does not work, it's a network issue and not a browser issue.

Comment: I have installed midori and I can access the website with it. what can I do now? it seems it is a problem with firefox?

Comment: It's weird that Midori worked, though. Maybe they don't make use of the DNS cache. I'am happy the DNS fix worked.

Comment: It does not make sense for midori to work if the problem was DNS issue. I thought my problem was with firefox.  just  for the sake of it, was there another way to solve this problem? I am interested in hearing what would you have suggested.

Comment: Maybe Firefox keeps a DNS cache itself which it obtains from Network Manager. In Linux, there are a thousand ways to fix or get around a problem. This is why people like me who answer questions almost always need more information. Other than clearing the DNS cache when you experience a problem like this, you can try restarting your router (small box which gives you internet). Most of the time, that will solve connection issues. And you can always use http://isup.me to check if a website is down (their problem) or up (which means it's your problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have an issue with the DNS resolver cache. The DNS resolver translates domain names to IP addresses and back. Probably the entry in your DNS cache is no longer valid.

You can try to refresh your cache by restarting the DNS service:

```
sudo service nscd restart
```

If that does not work, try this

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: restarting the DNS service resolved the problem thank you all